# Web Service Error path property must set before calling the send method

Tags: asp.net, web-services, web, webservice-client

> path property must set before calling the send method

What is the cause of this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The usually means that the WSDL that you are using doesn't have a Service section defined to say where the web service is located.  So the error is basically telling you that it doesn't know where to send the method call because there is no destination defined.

When you create an instance of the serivce try setting the Url property to the location of the service and then try calling the method again.